# restrict kafka topic partition distribute on only parts of brokers

Tags: apache-kafka

For a multi-tenant kafka cluster, I would like to control Topic partition distribution on specified kakfa brokers. For example topic-A can be on broker-1, broker-2; and topic-B can be on broker-3, broker-4.

Does kafka has such mechanism? For example, can we set a tag for broker and topic, only topic with same tag can be put on the broker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, it is part of how you configure your topics. From the [docs](http://kafka.apache.org/intro):

> Distribution The partitions of the log are distributed over the
>   servers in the Kafka cluster with each server handling data and
>   requests for a share of the partitions. Each partition is replicated
>   across a configurable number of servers for fault tolerance.
>
> Each partition has one server which acts as the "leader" and zero or
>   more servers which act as "followers". The leader handles all read and
>   write requests for the partition while the followers passively
>   replicate the leader. If the leader fails, one of the followers will
>   automatically become the new leader. Each server acts as a leader for
>   some of its partitions and a follower for others so load is well
>   balanced within the cluster.

you can specify the number of partitions and replicas and Kafka will distribute them, or you can specify where the partitions/replicas should be.

```
#non manual assignment example
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topic1 --replication-factor 2 --partitions 123
```

From [replication tools](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Replication+tools):

```
# Create topic with manual replica assignment
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic topic1 --replica-assignment 0:1:2,0:1:2,0:1:2
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a way we need to control it ourselves, if we use auto rebalance tooll such as cruise-control, then the it won't works, right?

Comment: I don't know what tools out there do and how, sorry